# Why do I need *, *:after {...} instead of just * {...}?

Tags: css

Could someone explain why the universal selector doesn't apply to :after? A relevant portion of the standard would be great, but also the rationale behind it.

**Edit**: I can see my question is poorly worded; my apologies. I mean that `* { color: green; }` makes pretty much all text in a document green, but does not apply to, say `#mypar:after { content:"newly-added content"; }`. I realize this content is not present in the original DOM... but it looks like `* { color: green; }` should suffice, instead of needing to write `*, *:after { color: green; }`.

I have also edited the title of my question for clarity.

**2nd edit**: This is bad... OK, I tried to provide a simple example and it didn't help. My question came up after reading [this article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/). Note that the author uses

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

instead of

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

Comment: why do you say it doesn't ? please explain further.

Comment: Do you mean `*:after { ... }`? Works perfectly for me. Wonderfully for `box-sizing` :)

Comment: It does work... see example at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/e37cH/

Comment: Please provide a concrete example of what doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: What he says is that *:after works, but he expects * {} to work the same effect.

Comment: Thanks to all for the feedback. Allendar, you're right. In fact, I learned that one needs `*, *:after` instead of just `*` by reading [this article by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) on `box-sizing`. Interestingly, he added `*:after` in a subsequent edit.

Comment: @eze It seems to work in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/9vSK2/

Comment: Note you can use `:after` instead of `*:after`.

Comment: Mohamad, as Jukka pointed out my example is bad as inheritance breaks the point I wanted to make. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal selector `*` matches any element, but pseudo-elements are not regarded as elements. They can only be matched by a selector that uses a pseudo-element selector such as `:after`.

In the case given in the question, the pseudo-element content would still be green when `* { color: green; }` is used and no rule overrides it. Even though a pseudo-element does not match `*`, the real element associated with it is matched, and `color` would be inherited from it. But if you tried `* { border: solid 1px }`, you would see that all elements have borders, but pseudo-elements do not (the `border` property is not inherited).

I don’t think there is any official rationale to this, but there does not seem to be use cases where pseudo-elements *should* match the universal selector.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough reply. The example I gave, trying to simplify matters, is no good. I came across this issue reading [this](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) article. I think not needing `*:after` or `:after` would feel more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors),

> An Asterisk (*) is the universal selector for CSS. It matches a single
>   **element** of any type.

But `:after` is not an element, is a **pseudo-element**. Then, it isn't matched by `*`.